# Can list conversion to string be accomplished with a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am wondering if `for row in purge_list:` in the following example, which works fine, can be transformed into one line using a list comprehension:

```
fnam = "purge_list.csv"
fH = open(fnam, 'w+')

out_str = ""

for row in purge_list:
    for str_element in row:
        out_str = str(str_element) + "," + out_str

    out_str = out_str + "\n"
    fH.write(out_str)
    out_str = ""

fH.close()
```

My goal is to take results returned in a list, and write them out as a comma-separated string.

Thanks.

### Edit

This is what the data looks like:

```
Device ID   Last Read   PremiseID   
80622121    2011-12-05 23:00:00 304096000   
80630175    2012-04-25 23:09:46 315080000   
80623426    2012-04-25 23:00:00 601012500   
80622084    2012-07-31 23:00:00 604013000   
80581425    2012-07-31 23:00:00 604034000
```

I appreciate the attention to this answer, the comments and answers.

Comment: *can* and *should* are two very different questions.  I think you probably *can*, but you probably *shouldn't*

Comment: @mgilson Why shouldn't? Too complicated? Overkill?

Comment: Generally, list comprehensions are used to build lists, not for some side-effect (like writing to a file).

Comment: csv.writer was not doing what I wanted, although I may not have been using it correctly.

Comment: You inner list can be done more succinctly though:  `out_str += ','.join(str(x) for x in reversed(row)) + '\n'`

Comment: Please provide some example input and expected output, it looks like your current code would print all previous lines each time through the outer loop since you aren't setting it back to an empty string on each iteration.

Comment: Good point. I'll fix that. Was unintential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should do what you want, please provide some example input and expected output if it is not the result you are looking for:

```
out_str = '\n'.join(','.join(map(str, reversed(row))) for row in purge_list)
```

Your code appears to print each line in order, but the elements in each line are reversed and joined on commas, which is what my code should do.

The other thing your code does (which I think is unintentional), is print duplicates of some lines.

`','.join(map(str, reversed(row)))` is equivalent to your inner for loop (except that yours would include a trailing comma), by putting this inside of a `for row in purge_list` generator we can get the correct output for each line, and then `'\n'.join` is used to create one big string from all of the lines.  You may also want a trailing newline, which you can do by adding `+ '\n'` to the very end of my one-liner.

**edit:** If you don't want to reverse anything, just remove the `reversed()` call from above.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your edit -- This is a somewhat tractable way to do it:

```
FH.writelines([','.join(str(x) for x in reversed(row)) for row in purge_list])
```

But it is still pretty difficult to read.  I would just get rid of the inner loop using `join` and `reversed`.

Comment: You need to add newline characters as writelines does add it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep:

```
>>> purge_list = [ ["a","b"], ["c","d"] ]
>>> ",".join( reversed( [ str(element) for row in purge_list for element in row  ]) )
'd,c,b,a'
```

To note:

- The `join()` method on a string puts that string as a delimiter between each element in the list passed to it
- List comprehensions can nest, but it's interpreted from the inside out, which is counter-intuitive to some people (me included)
- Your code was putting each new element at the start of the string, which I've accomplished by reversing the list before the join

Comment: You might be able to get the final string correct, but you won't get the correct thing to write to the file this way.  (assuming OP's code is correct).  With your list, OP's code would write `'d,c'` and then `'d,c\nb,a'` which isn't what you have.

Comment: True; I'm not certain whether that's really what OP wants.

Comment: Me neither.  OP said "...following example, which works fine", but I post thing assuming they work without checking on occasion ;^)

Comment: csv library was writing a list [ stuff1, stuff2, ...] into the .csv file. What I wanted was simple, just a .csv file. I've fixed on error based on comments here, which was to zero out the out_str after each write. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
csv='\n'.join([','.join(map(str,row)) for row in purge_list])
```

Of course you can replace the map with another string comprehension but I think map is simpler.

Edit:
I missed the reversed row in the  code. So, F.J's answer is the correct one.

Edit again:
To get a trailing new line (new line after the last line) use the code:

```
csv=['%s\n' % line for line in [','.join(map(str,row)) for row in purge_list]]
```

Here is the equivalent of your code using `with` statement:

```
with open(fnam, 'w+') as file:
    file.writelines('%s\n' % line for line in [','.join(map(str,row)) for row in purge_list])
```

Comment: There was no intention of reversing anything. That was an example error on my part, which I fixed.

Comment: Also, you can remove the `[]` brackets and get a generator instead of a list comprehension, which is (in my opinion) more readable.